# Using animation nodes to create / animate different 3D Polyhedrons solids using the expression node

Tags: animation-nodes, geometry

Using animation nodes to make 3D platonic / geometric / polyhedrons solids using expression node.  The reason I want to do this is to animate them in different ways. Some of the objects would be Dodecahedrons, Tetartoid, pyritohedral honeycomb, etc...

But I haven't been able to find examples that creates these solids using animation nodes.

The formulas / equations I was planning to use was [link1](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhedron.html) and [link2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron)

I did read about the expression node here [link3](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/expression.html) but couldn't find anything about polyhedrons.

Some of them would do things like this:

[image: animated image]

Comment: The expression node only lets you play with a single python line. I think you will have to use a "script" node for these kinds of results. Do you happen to have one simple example of a formula to create such polyhedrons ?

Comment: @Gorgious is this what you referring to?  https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface/

The only thing I've found so far for polyhedrons are the links above hence my original question.

Comment: I was referring to the script node, https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/script.html that lets you write more advanced equations in the python language using a text block. My question was : Do you know what inputs should go into such a script or, are you looking for already available equations to create your polyhedrons ? Because if this is the latter, I'm afraid Animation nodes can't provide you these out of the box

Comment: @Gorgious Sorry I don't know what inputs should go in the script that was one of my questions above `"I haven't been able to find examples that creates these solids using animation nodes."`

Comment: Alright, then the answer is you won't find them in the add-on, you have to provide them